# Remove SQL link from DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# application in which I have a `DataSet`. When we started the project, the `DataSet` was created using the designer, based on an SQL database. However, things have changed and the `DataSet` is now populated by de-serializing a JSON string (which comes from an API). The database doesn't even exist anymore (at least not in the eyes of the application).

My problem is this: The `DataSet` still appears to be linked to the (no longer existing) SQL database. For instance, if I try to add a column to a `DataTable` I get the following error:

> Failed to add column.
>
> Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login.
>
> The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'MyUserName'.
>
> at DataObjectSupport(423,6)

How do I remove this link between SQL and the `DataSet`, so that all I have left is an "empty container"?

**UPDATE**

I have found the following code multiple times in the file `MyDataSet.Designer.cs`:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "15.0.0.0")]
private void InitConnection() {
    this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    this._connection.ConnectionString = global::VendorEquipmentData.Properties.Settings.Default.MyDatabase;
}
```

It seems to exist for each `TableAdapter`. The problem is that each `DataTable` has a table adapter called **Fill, GetData ()**. But I cannot delete these adapters, even though I am not using them (the "Delete" command in the context menu is disabled).

Comment: Sounds like you still have code that is referencing your old connection. You haven't posted any of your code, however, so you'll need to do that people any of the volunteers here can help you.

Comment: you might have a reference to the database in your config file

Comment: @Larnu I am struggling a bit to find some relevant code to post. The code base for the `DataSet` is enormous (since it is autogenerated) and most of it is quite irrelevant. I will see if I can find any code related to the database.

Comment: After having searched the code, the database connection is specified in quite a lot of places in both `MyDataSet.xsd` and MyDataSet.Designer.cs` (see update to main post). I am struggling to find out, if there is a way for me to delete this, without destroying everything.

Comment: Try this: [How to: Remove Data Sources from the Data Sources Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233820.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own issue. I searched for 'MyDataBase' in the entire project, and ended up deleting a bunch of code lines in otherwise auto-generated code. The lines I deleted was in two different files. Each line existed multiple times in the file.

**MyDataSet.Designer.cs**

```
// Removed this line
this._connection.ConnectionString = global::VendorEquipmentData.Properties.Settings.Default.MyDatabase;
```

**MyDataSet.xsd**

```
<!-- Removed these lines -->
<MainSource>
  <DbSource ConnectionRef="MyDataBase (Settings)" DbObjectName="MyDataBase .Schema.Table" DbObjectType="View" FillMethodModifier="Public" FillMethodName="Fill" GenerateMethods="Both" GenerateShortCommands="false" GeneratorGetMethodName="GetData" GeneratorSourceName="Fill" GetMethodModifier="Public" GetMethodName="GetData" QueryType="Rowset" ScalarCallRetval="System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx" UseOptimisticConcurrency="true" UserGetMethodName="GetData" UserSourceName="Fill">
    <SelectCommand>
      <DbCommand CommandType="Text" ModifiedByUser="false">
        <CommandText>SELECT Name, Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Schema.Table</CommandText>
        <Parameters />
      </DbCommand>
    </SelectCommand>
  </DbSource>
</MainSource>
```